# Extension UIButton only when conforming to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, protocols

I'm trying to create several extensions for `UIButton` so I can add some functionality easily just by adding a protocol to a custom button. It'd be a lot easier if I didn't have to override some methods in `UIButton` so I'm thinking I'll have to make an extension for `UIButton` itself.

For example, I have several protocols my custom buttons can conform to:

```
protocol CustomLayer { }

protocol ButtonSound { }
```

So far I only managed to create an extension for `UIButton` without any constraints (these are simplified versions):

```
// Only when the button conforms to protocol CustomLayer
extension UIButton {
    override public class func layerClass() -> AnyClass { return CAShapeLayer.self }
}

// Only when the button conforms to protocol ButtonSound
extension UIButton {
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1104)
    }
}
```

I've read posts I can make an extension for the protocol itself with a where clause for the class `UIButton`:

```
extension CustomLayer where Self: UIButton { }
```

But then I can't override any methods of `UIButton` itself.

Other suggestions like subclassing works, but certain buttons can't have the same functionality:

```
class A: CustomLayer { } // Can't have ButtonSound, single subclass works
class B: ButtonSound { } // Can't have CustomLayer, single subclass works

class C: CustomLayer, ButtonSound { } // Error: multiple inheritance from classes
```

Comment: You can't add a constraint to an extension as it would lead to the potential for multiple inheritance

Comment: You can't just add protocol conformance to "button", you add it to some `UIButton` subclass. So just make extensions of these subclasses.

Comment: @Paulw11: I was afraid of that, I noticed when creating this question in some cases I had multiple inheritances. I'll leave the question open for a bit, perhaps some other suggestions might show up. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

protocol BackButtonDelegate {

    func BackButtonAction(sender:UIButton)
}

class NavigationBack: UIButton
{
     var delegate : BackButtonDelegate!

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)
        self.setTitle("Back", forState: .Normal)
        self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica",size: 12)
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "back-arrow"), forState: .Normal)

        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NavigationBack.click(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

   }
    func click(sender:UIButton)
    {
        if delegate != nil
        {
            delegate!.BackButtonAction(sender)
        }
    }

}
```